# How to do a search/replace on a file on the fly?

Tags: java, file, replace, io

My java application loads an XML file and then parses the XML.

What I would like to is a search/replace on the file before I create the SAXBuilder.  How can I do this in memory ( without having to write to the file ) ?

Here's my code, and where I envision doing the search/replace :

```
private String xmlFile = "D:\\mycomputer\\extract.xml";
File myXMLFile = new File(xmlFile);

// TODO
// REPLACE ALL "<content>" in xmlFile with "<content><![CDATA["
// REPLACE ALL "</content>" with "]]></content>"

SAXBuilder builder =  new SAXBuilder("org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser");

document = builder.build(new File(myXMLFile));
```

Comment: How would you replace items in a file without writing them?

Answer (score 1):

You answered to the question yourself - read the whole file into a StringBuilder, perform the replace in it and then call SAXParser.

The string can be passed to SAXBuilder using StringReader:

`StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder ();
loadFIleContent (filePath, sb);
document = builder.build (new StringReader (sb.toString ()));`

P.S.: follow up to theglauber's answer:

If the file is really big (~100Mb) it's impractical to fully read it into memory as well as parsing it into a DOM tree. In this case you should consider using SAXParser and replacing as the file being parsed.

Comment: My XML files are about 10MB, which I think is not too bad.

Comment: Then be prepared that after parsing it will take additional ~100Mb to hold created DOM tree in the memory.

Answer (score 1):

Read the file into memory, do the search/replace, and use the SAXBuilder(StringReader) method.

Answer (score 1):

You can first read file to string with [apache commons io](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) and then change the input source for the `SaxBuilder` as in the following code snippet:

```
String fileStr = FileUtils.readFileToString(myXMLFile);
fileStr = fileStr.replaceAll("<content>","<content><![CDATA[");
fileStr = fileStr.replaceAll("</content>","]]></content>");
SAXBuilder builder =  new SAXBuilder("org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser");
document = builder.build(new ByteArrayInputStream(fileStr.getBytes()));
```

Comment: It's better to use StringReader instead of ByteArrayInputStream to avoid using String.getBytes which would create memory overhead if the file is quite large.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how large these files are, either read the file into a String, do your replacements in memory and build the XML from the String, or spawn a new thread to read the file, do the replacements and output, then build the XML from the output of that thread.

(I would suggest parsing and modifying the XML tree or using a XML filter, but i suspect you want to do this string-based replacement because the current content of your files is not correct XML.)